# Reordering list items by onclick with ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

**Learning ReactJs, i would implement this by using the best practise. Please anyone add another feature or comment with your solutions.**

I'm trying to build a reorder list items component by clicking on a set of up/down buttons.

1) How can i show all the props component values and his bgColor?

2) For handling the events I should have to use the constructor and inside add onClickUp() & onClickDown() methods?

**FruitList Component:**

```
class FruitList extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { // set new state for bind key items
         items : [
           {'id': 1, 'name': 'orange', 'bgColor': '#f9cb9c'},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'lemon','bgColor' : '#fee599'},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'strawberry', 'bgColor': '#e06666'},
           {'id': 4, 'name': 'apple', 'bgColor' : '#b6d7a7'}
         ]
      }
   }

   onMoveUp = (key) => {
      if(key === 0) return; // disable method when the key its equal to 0 
      const { items } = this.props; // assign props to items for don't repeat my self 
      const index = key - 1;  // save in memory index value less than one
      const itemAbove = items[index]; // save in memory items index  
      items[key - 1] = items[key]; // match id value with the key object
      items[key] = itemAbove; 
      this.setState({ items }); // set new state 
   }

   onMoveDown = (key) => {
      const { items } = this.props;
      if(key === items.length - 1) return;
      const index = key + 1;
      const itemBelow = items[index];
      items[key + 1] = items[key];
      items[key] = itemBelow;
      this.setState({ items });
   }

   render() {
      const { items } = this.state;

      return (
         <ul>
           {items.map((item, key) =>
               <li key={key} style={{ backgroundColor: item.bgColor }}>
                  <div className="fruitsId">{ key + 1 }</div>
                  <div className="fruitsName">{ item.name }</div>
                  <div className="fruitsArrows">
                     <span onClick={() => this.onMoveUp(key)}>&#x25B2;</span>
                     <span onClick={() => this.onMoveDown(key)}>&#x25BC;</span>
                  </div>
               </li>
            )}
         </ul>
      );
   }

}
```

**App.js Component:**

```
class App extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         fruitList : [
           {'id': 1, 'name': 'orange', 'bgColor': '#f9cb9c'},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'lemon','bgColor' : '#fee599'},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'strawberry', 'bgColor': '#e06666'},
           {'id': 4, 'name': 'apple', 'bgColor' : '#b6d7a7'}
         ]         
      }
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <FruitList items={this.state.fruitList} />
      );
   }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

[SandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/m412zk7r68)

Comment: By your posted code, the `id`, `name`, and `bgColor` props on the `<FruitsList/>` component are all undefined. Is that part of your question?

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Ted! is the answer to my 1st question. I want to print dynamically the items.

Comment: @MartinDiIorio don't set the state outside of the constructor if you are using extending from Component. Have a read at [using the state correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Comment: @c-chavez Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should [lift the sate up](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up) and provide callbacks `onMoveUp/onMoveDown` and pass them to `FruitList` or you can have one `onMove(id: number, direction: number)` and pass there `+1` (enum DOWN) or `-1` (enum UP) to move the right direction. See the code below.

Also the method `handleMove` in the code below can be moved into `FruitList` class if you want and name it for example `handleListChanged` so `App` will only receive new list every time it is changed. I guess my code is better for you since you are starting with React.

```js
const UP = -1
const DOWN = 1

class FruitList extends React.Component {
   render() {
      const {fruitList, onMove} = this.props

      return (
         <ul>
           {fruitList.map((item) =>
               <li key={item.id} style={{ backgroundColor: item.bgColor }}>
                  <div className="fruitsId">{item.id}</div>
                  <div className="fruitsName">{item.name}</div>
                  <div className="fruitsArrows">
                     <a onClick={() => onMove(item.id, UP)}>&#x25B2;</a>
                     <a onClick={() => onMove(item.id, DOWN)}>&#x25BC;</a>
                  </div>
               </li>
            )}
         </ul>
      );
   }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { // set new state for bind key items
    items: [
      {'id': 1, 'name': 'orange', 'bgColor': '#f9cb9c'},
      {'id': 2, 'name': 'lemon','bgColor' : '#fee599'},
      {'id': 3, 'name': 'strawberry', 'bgColor': '#e06666'},
      {'id': 4, 'name': 'apple', 'bgColor' : '#b6d7a7'},
    ]
  }

  handleMove = (id, direction) => {
    const {items} = this.state

    const position = items.findIndex((i) => i.id === id)
    if (position < 0) {
      throw new Error("Given item not found.")
    } else if (direction === UP && position === 0 || direction === DOWN && position === items.length - 1) {
      return // canot move outside of array
    }

    const item = items[position] // save item for later
    const newItems = items.filter((i) => i.id !== id) // remove item from array
    newItems.splice(position + direction, 0, item)

    this.setState({items: newItems})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FruitList fruitList={this.state.items} onMove={this.handleMove} />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.body
);
```

```css
/* Add your css styles here */
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
    justify-content: center;
}
li div {
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.fruitsId,
    .fruitsArrows {
    width: 50px;
}
.fruitsName {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple issues. First, you need to map the properties within the items in fruitlist, and your variable for bgColor needs to be consistent. See the functioning example below to at least get you started with a functioning component:

```js
class FruitsList extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <ul>
           {this.props.items.map((item, key) =>
               <li style={{ backgroundColor: item.bgColor }}>
                  <div className="fruitsId">{ item.id }</div>
                  <div className="fruitsName">{ item.name }</div>
                  <div className="fruitsArrows">
                     <span>&#x25B2;</span>
                     <span>&#x25BC;</span>                    
                  </div>
               </li>            
            )}
         </ul>
      );
   }
}

FruitsList.defaultsProps = {Items:[]}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
     fruitsList : [
       { 'id': 1, 'name': 'orange', 'bgColor': '#f9cb9c'},
       { 'id': 2, 'name': 'lemon','bgColor' : '#fee599'},
       { 'id': 3, 'name': 'strawberry', 'bgColor': '#e06666'},
       { 'id': 4, 'name': 'apple', 'bgColor' : '#b6d7a7'}
     ]         
  } 
   render() {
      return (
         <FruitsList items={this.state.fruitsList} />
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```